# Entity Framework Core Sqlite data not getting fetched when run in ADMIN mode

Tags: sqlite, entity-framework-core

I have never seen this strange issue. I have a winform console app which is using Sqlite database and I am using Entity Framework Core Sqlite for data insert, update, etc.

Code that is displaying data is pretty straight forward

```
List<BL.EndPoint> LiEpS = dbContext.EndPoints.ToList();
```

When I open my Winform in normal way, it is loading data but when I open as "Run as Administrator" it is not showing any data. See image below

[image]

What's strange is that when I open the database in Sqlite Browser, I am amazed to see No data in one of the table then how come when I open it in Normal mode data is coming for that table? See image below
[image]

1) I am extremely puzzled. How come data is not showing in Sqlite Browser when I open the table but it is showing when the application is run in Normal way?

2) Is there any chance Entity Framework Sqlite Core saves data but it isn't visible in the sqlite browser?

3) How can the same code show data when run in normal mode but doesn't show data when run as ADMIN?

Comment: How is the application finding the database?  In other words, what is the path of the database from within the application?  Is it the path a user-dependent value?

Comment: Perkins I had added numerous message boxes throughout and path is coming correct and is same for both the conditions.

Comment: A couple other routine debugging questions:  You don't mention what context SQLite Browser is running... user or Admin?  Have you checked the file and folder permissions?

Comment: Sqlite Browser has nothing to do with my app, I just wanted to see the data in Sqlite Db. When I open database in sqlite browser, it is not showing any data but when an application which uses the sqlite db is run in normal mode, it shows data (then how come that data is not getting shown by the sqlite browser?)

And when I RUN it as ADMIN my application which uses sqlite browser, it doesn't show any data either. Very puzzled I am

Comment: I already understood that.  Although SQLite Browser might not have to do with your app, *the behavior* can be compared.  I asked about what user context for SQLite Browser so that the situation could be COMPARED to each other.  In other words, you should use all possible resources to deduce what the problem might be.  If you are using SQLite Browser as an ADMIN user, then at least it is consistent with your app behavior.  But if you are using SQLite Browser as a non-admin user, then it is even more confusing that you get an empty table.

Comment: Your response also made no mention of the file permissions.  Is your app catching any exceptions that are not being reported?  Are you certain there are no errors/exceptions within the app that could reveal what the problem is?

Comment: I have opened Sqlite browser in both mode, normal as well as admin and the behavior is same. I have kept all message boxes, etc open and no exception is thrown. Code which fetches record is 

 List<BL.EndPoint> LiEpS = dbContext.EndPoints.ToList();

and it returns 0 count in ADMIN mode whereas it returns 68 in normal mode which is correct.

Comment: Some exceptions might be suppressed but could be shown in the debug output window.  I'm just helping explore options, because something is either keeping the DB from being opened properly or you are actually opening a different DB but don't realize it.

Comment: I also expected the same and hence had added message boxes almost on every lines to catch the flow. No issue is coming up. I can show you via screenshare if you have 10 mins on this, this will make it easier for you to comprehend

Comment: I also expected the same and hence had added message boxes almost on every lines to catch the flow. No issue is coming up. I can show you via screen share if you have 10 mins on this, this will make it easier for you to comprehend

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202301/discussion-between-sujit-singh-and-c-perkins).